# Electron/React build application package index.html missing react bundle scripts *white page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, electron

I have built a react application and installed Electron, and I can run npm start and the electron app opens up and runs my React application. So I want to package it up into an executable. I'm on a Macbook Pro, so I run this:

```
sudo electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/bolt_circle.icns --out=release-builds
```

This builds out my application and I can run it, but the application is just a blank white page. The console shows no errors. After poking around and comparing the development application that works and this packaged version, I see that the packaged version loads the html file but does not have the React bundle/chunk scripts at the end of the  that I see in the working version. This appears to me to be a job for the React bundler...but ..er...I don't really know how to dig into this being that the React app is a "create-react-app" and all the stuff is hidden from me.

So, I don't know if package.json will help or not. I don't know what information would be helpful to solve this problem.

Working Version:
[image: Working Version HTML source]

Not Working Version:
[image: Not working version HTML source]

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the code where you `loadURL` into the window?

Comment: I was eventually able to fix this...I can't remember how off the top of my head. I will try to report the details of how I fixed it when I find my brain and the time. In the mean time, I have uploaded my working version of electronReact, with getting started instructions in the readme: https://gitlab.com/cjohnweb/electronreact